# Get variable from a script using chrome.tabs.executeScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension and I have to take the result from a `chrome.tabs.executeScript` in background page. But when I try to use the variable, Chrome shows "undefined".

**Background Page:**

```
chrome.tabs.onClicked.addListener(function() {
 var quant
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
  code: "document.getElementsByTagName['strong']"
 }, function(q1) {
  quant = q1
 })
 alert(q1.legth)
})
```

How can I get the variables from my scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You have three problems:

1. length is misspelled
2. q1 is not available outside its function
3. executeScript is asynchronous, so the callback happens after the
   alert

Comment: This is just a example. My doubt is about how can I get a variable from injected script using the executeScript.

Comment: Content script would be an easier option in such cases. If you want to use the variable in your background page, just send it from content script to background page using message passing.